# sorting rows of data frames which are in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sorting

I have browsed extensively through SO and havnt found something closely appropriate to what I am looking for.

I have a list of data frames ds. each data frame has 5 columns, A,B,C,D,E,F and I would like to sort the rows in each data frame in this list by columns E and F.
So one data frame might not be sorted as compared to another but the rows in each data frame must be sorted in ascending order. columns E and F are both integer values.

I have tried to use the order() function

```
ds[with(ds, order(ds$E, ds$F)),]
```

but it gives an error argument 1 is not a vector. For sorting data in a dataframe this would work fine but i am getting stuck since the data frames are in a list. 
Have also tried iterating but doesnt work (P.S. Please dont laugh, complete beginner here. ). where extkeys is the number of dataframes in the list (22)

> for (i in length(extkeys))
>          {
>               ds2 <- ds[[i]][order(ds$WEEK,ds$YEAR,)]
>          }

Can someone suggest any alternative/correct way of doing it?

Newbie to R here and dataset is too complicated. Would appreciate the help :)

Comment: `lapply(ds, function(x) x[order(x$E, x$F), ])`

Comment: It works though required a bit more tweaking owing to the nature of my sorting keys. I really need to get a hang of these apply functions

Comment: Definite duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270117/how-to-sort-all-dataframes-in-a-list-of-dataframes-on-the-same-column. You mustn't have browsed very long!

Comment: Thank you so much :)  Also I cant find a way of accepting this as a solution.

Comment: @Edward had found that but was not sure if it would sort the data frames within themselves or the content within data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand my comment above into answer, you can use `lapply` to apply a sort to each data frame in your list:

```
lapply(ds, function(x) x[order(x$E, x$F), ])
```