# Sort a data frame stored within list in R

Tags: r, list

I am trying to sort a data frame that is stored within a list. I need to preserve the list in its original format, because the list is the output of a specialized model, and I need to run something else from the new/sorted list. Here is a sample list with a nested data frame:

```
original_list <- list(
    dataset = data.frame("country" = c("USA", "France"),
                        "output" = c(10,20)),
    other_list = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
  )
```

Using these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270117/how-to-sort-all-dataframes-in-a-list-of-dataframes-on-the-same-column) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415650/sorting-rows-of-data-frames-which-are-in-a-list-in-r), I attempted to solve the issue myself and sort the nested data frame by `country` as follows:

```
sorted_list <- lapply(original_list, function(dataset){
  dataset[order(dataset$country),]
})
```

However, I am getting the following error: "Error in order(dataset$country) : argument 1 is not a vector". How can I sort the nested data frame by `country`?

Comment: The posts you link to are about sorting many df's with the same structure by the same column, you have a simpler problem, to sort one df by one column. Do it directly, no loops: `original_list$dataset <- original_list$dataset[order(original_list$dataset$country), ]`.

Comment: `lapply(original_list, \(x)if(is.data.frame(x))x[order(x$country),] else x)`